# FindBys and List<WebElement> always return null list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

As far as my understanding goes, FindBys Annotation in pagefactory returns you elements which satisfies  all the condition mentioned inside. The code below always returns 0 elements.

Similarly,If I'm using FindAll annotation with same id and Xpath attribute it is returning me 2 webelements.  Can anyone help me in understanding the results.

```html
 @FindBys
 (   
   {
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_divWelcome']"),
    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ctl00_divWelcome")
    
   }
   )
 public List<WebElement> allElementsInList;
```

Comment: We can't be sure why it's returning 0 elements without a link to the page. It's possible that ID is not present, is not visible, or there is a delay in page loading that is causing it to return 0. As for why FindAll returns 2, I'm not sure but I would guess that it's executing two searches, each of which returns one element. The search isn't smart enough to realize that they both are the same element. Why would you do these two searches anyway? They are going to return the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong.

The [documentation for @FindBy](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBys.html) says:

> Used to mark a field on a Page Object to indicate that lookup should use a series of `@FindBy` tags **in a chain** as described in org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.ByChained

Further, the [documentation for ByChained](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/ByChained.html) says:

> Mechanism used to locate elements within a document using a series of other lookups. This class will find all DOM elements that matches each of the locators in sequence, e.g. `driver.findElements(new ByChained(by1, by2))` will find all elements that match by2 and appear under an element that matches by1.

So in your example, you are looking for an element by XPath with a specific ID, and then its child element by the same ID ... which, of course, is not going to return anything.

Comment: Thank you @SiKing . Can you please shed some light on findAll method as well.

Comment: @ARJUNU `@FindAll` works like an OR condition: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/FindAll.html